# How to create price format for product in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am a beginner in Magento. I can create simple product for each category. I have one query for creating product. In admin panel, I want to create a custom option in `managed product` menu.
In my custom option, set of product size can generated `$89`, individual top of product size can be generated `$57` and bottom of product size can be generated `$57`.In this product can be depend upon size.

For example:
 select option
     --product with same size (`$89`)
     --product with different size (individual top `$57` and bottom `$57`).

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is the ability to set prices based off of a specific product combination.

For example:

A product with an attribute of `size` and `set` would have a specific price assigned to it.

*`set` will represent the section of clothing the customer wants (top, bottom or top & bottom).*

**Combination 1** | Size: 10 | Set: Top | Price: $57

**Combination 2** | Size: 10 | Set: Bottom | Price: $57

**Combination 3** | Size: 10 | Set: Top & Bottom | Price: $89

To do this, you'll have to modify the way Magento handles pricing for associated products.  What you do is create a simple product for each combination, then assign it to the configurable product.

Then, to get the pricing right you can install the [Simple Configurable Products](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple) extension.  This will display the pricing based of the assigned products of the configurable.

For example, if a user selects `Size: 10` and `Set: Bottom` they will be given a price of `$57` because it matches **Combination 2**.

If the user selects `Size: 10` and `Set: Bottom & Top`, the price will change to `$89` because it matches **Combination 3**.

---

**[A Word of Warning]**

Installing the Simple Configurable Products plugin will fundamentally change the way Magento displays pricing on the frontend.  There will be no more "percentage based" markup, markdown based on attribute values.  The pricing for configurable products are directly related to the products assigned to the configurable products.